# How to delete a colon : after my json.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a probleme when I use json.stringify, it returns me a json with a colon after the json

```js
axios.post('http://54.196.61.131/api/v0/user/250/product/add/scan',
        JSON.stringify({
      
          name: currentProduct.product.product_name_fr,
          brand: currentProduct.product.brands,
          image: currentProduct.product.image_front_thumb_url,
          product_quantity: currentProduct.product.quantity,
          ingredients: currentProduct.product.ingredients_text,
          quantity: parseInt(quantite, 10),
          nutriscore_grade: currentProduct.product.nutriscore_grade,
          expiration_date: expDate,
          barcode: currentProduct.code,
        }))
```

it returns me with a : at the end, so I have an 500 error to my API:

```js
{"name":"Farine de blé suprême","brand":"Francine","image":"https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/306/811/070/3232/front_fr.37.100.jpg","product_quantity":"1 kg","ingredients":"Farine de blé type 45.","quantity":6,"nutriscore_grade":"a","barcode":"3068110703232","expiration_date":"2020-07-24T10:41:04.000Z"}:
```

Thank you

Comment: No, it won't because this wouldn't be valid JSON. Please add a [mcve] (preferable as [runnable snippet `<>`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) that shows the actual problem.

Comment: Try console logging the data and it's stringified form, normally you never get a colon after stringifying at it's end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try serializing your data.

```
serialize = function (obj) {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj)
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        }
    return str.join("&");
}
```

```
axios.post('http://54.196.61.131/api/v0/user/250/product/add/scan', serialize({
    // Your JSON data
})
```